# Trouble installing wget on Mac os

Tags: macos, makefile, terminal, wget

I'm trying to install wget-1.19.tar.xz.

What i did :

```
$ ./configure --with-ssl=openssl && make
$ sudo make install
```

Here the message error :

> There seems to be no Makefile in this directory. You must run
>   ./configure before running 'make'. make: ***
>   [abort-due-to-no-makefile] Error 1

Makefile.am and Makefile.in are in my directory.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You could also use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/index_nl.html) for this if you'd like. Simply install it and run `brew install wget`.

Comment: Run just `./configure --with-ssl=openssl` by itself and check the console messages it emits.

If `./configure` completes successfully, toward the end of its output, you should see a series of lines that start with 'config.status: creating Makefile'

If you don’t see that, it seems `./configure` must be stopping for some reason before it gets there.

So the `./configure` output must be emitting some other message before it stops, and you want to look at the message and see if it helps you figure out what you need to get to get it to actually generate the `Makefile` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found this super useful guide that allows you to quickly install Rudix wget in less than 5 mins. Just installed it myself.

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-and-configure-wget-on-os-x/

- For the easiest method, just go with the first option, download the package from the link(comes directly from Rudix) 
  rudix,org/packages/wget,html
- Rudix offers wget for multiple [supported Mac OS X versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us1QT.png)
- If you decide against installation with a .pkg, there are more options available along with full walk throughs of the installation process at the first link that I mentioned.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same,
I recommend installing wget via homebrew!, follow the below commands for smooth wget installation:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

`brew install wget`

Then you are good to go..

Answer (score 0):

The new link is:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Comment: This would be better as a comment (or proposed edit) on the existing answer linking to the Homebrew installer. We don't need a new competing answer every time things move.